# JavaScript setTimeout will not die.

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I made a photogallery and is AJAX powered. Below are the relevant pieces of code.

```
    if (isset($_POST['stopss'])){
    echo'<script type="text/javascript">
    clearTimeout(setss);
    </script>';
    }

    if (isset($_POST['startss'])){
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var setss = window.setTimeout('delayer(\''+src+'\',\''+dir+'\',\''+title+'\',\''+width+'\',\''+height+'\',\''+img+'\')',5000);
    </script>
    <?
    }
```

The delayer function passes params for a new modal box window (new AJAX request).
The problem as I see it. The timeout gets started when a user clicks the Slideshow button.
Even though they press the Stop Slideshow button (this reloads the AJAX page), the timer is still running (in the background) and in clearTimeout(setss), setss is no longer available (because of the new AJAX page request) so the clearTimeout fails to clear.

Is there any way to kill the timeout running in the background? Even if the modalbox window is closed, 5 seconds later it opens and happily keeps playing the slide show.

btw, this is the modalbox call.
        Modalbox.show('../b-gal-scripts/ajaxgal.php', {title: title, overlayOpacity: .1, width: width, height: height, method: 'post', params: {src: next, dir: dir, img: img, ssimg: next} }); return false;

Comment: Not the answer, but everytime someone passes a string to `setTimeout`, god kills a kitten. `var setss = window.setTimeout(function() { delayer(src, dir, title, width, height, img) }, 5000);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having a little difficulty understanding your problem, but I hope this helps.

1. When a page is reloaded, the previous instance of the page, and any state associated with it ceases to exist.  As a result, the timeout has been stopped.  Essentially, if the global `setSS` doesn't exist, then neither does the timeout to which it refers, therefore, that timeout cannot be responsible for starting the slideshow.
2. When an active page is served from something like PHP, the work of the server (WRT the creation of any content of the page) is done.  No more content can subsequently be written to the page.  Your clearTimeout is essentially useless, as it could only clear a timeout that is set during the load of the page.  It won't write a new script element into the existing page.
3. Variables are not shared across pages, so if you are setting the timeout in one page, and clearing it in another, that will not work.

So, in order to clear the timeout, you need to call `clearTimeout` in the same page (and instance of that page) as the `setTimeout`, and that call must be executed after the `setTimeout`.

If none of the above apply to your situation, then is it possible that `$_POST['startss']` and `$_POST['stopss']` are set in the same request?  If so, the new page will create a new timeout after the attempt to clear it, and will therefore display the slideshow.

(as an aside, using a closure to create a function to pass to setTimeout will be more readable than compiling a string that calls a function).

Answer (score 2):

### The problem

When you reload the page, the old JavaScript code (for the previous request) stops running and the new one is executed.

The problem is that you first call `clearTimeout(setss)` and later define what `setss` really is.

### A couple additional problems

A few tips:

1. **Do not mix quoting styles**, you are creating a mess this way.
2. If you want quotes within quotes, just **use the fact there are different quotes** like that:

   ```
   var setss = window.setTimeout("delayer('"+src+'","'+dir+'","'+title+'","'+width+'","'+height+'","'+img+'")',5000);
   ```
3. ...and preferably get used to **event-based programming** and **closures** when coding JavaScript, like that:

   ```
   var sets = window.setTimeout(function(){
       delayer(src, dir, title, width, height, img);
   }, 5000);
   ```

### Final version of your code

Your code should look like the following:

```
if (isset($_POST['startss']) && !isset($_POST['stopss'])){
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var setss = window.setTimeout(function(){
            delayer(src, dir, title, width, height, img);
        }, 5000);
    </script>
    <?
}
```

It makes use of the fact, that you do not need to first output a script that is executed only to immediately stop it if not needed. Just make PHP condition to check if you want it to be executed, the output it.

Second, the JS has been changed from using strings (which is totally messy) to using anonymous functions. Take a closer look into that.

Did it help?

Comment: clearTimeout(setss) is only called if the stop slideshow button was clicked, oterwise it is ignored. <br> likewise the setTimeout is only called if the start slideshow buttom is clicked. <br> The main page does not change but the modalbox overlay changes with each button click. <br> @Tadeck, will take your advice, I'm a jS noob. <br>

Comment: @LorenWolsiffer: Yes, but it is called before `setTimeout` is called. You see, the problem here is that you are assuming the code from the previous request is still executing, while it is not. JavaScript from the previous request stopped executing when the page reloaded.

Comment: @LorenWolsiffer: Are you saying the page is not reloading? I may have misinterpreted what you were saying. I believe that code is a bigger problem than I previously thought. You should really stick to **event-based programming**, when using JavaScript and **attach event handlers** to the "start" and "stop" buttons. Because you are beginning your journey with JavaScript, I suggest using [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials).

Comment: You can see it in use here floridayachtscharter.com/exterior-pictures/ I'm sure the problem is in the new page request where setss is not available. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: What I think is happening, the AJAX output script sets the timeout in the main browser window, then when the AJAX output script gets called again setss is no longer available, is there something like parent.window.clearTimeout(setss);?

Comment: I have to go do dinner and what I am thinking is add an onclick event to the stop slideshow link and then do clearTimeout(setss); before the ajax page reloads.

Comment: @LorenWolsiffer: Actually it looks like with each slide your `setss` is overwritten. So basically stop getting and executing JavaScript from these requests, this is not the way to go. Just stick with one code base, preferably in single JS file. Then start using some framework with its methods of binding event handlers and life will become easier. So basically, to begin with: remove both `<script>` tags from the slides, then bind events to these links (using jQuery's `.on()` or `.delegate()`, depending on jQuery's version), test, debug, ask questions.

Comment: @LorenWolsiffer: Also there is another problem: the POST data you are checking on the server seems not to be sent. Check it using some debugging tools like Firebug in Chrome or built-in Google Chrome tools.